# How to get last load params from Ext.Store

Tags: extjs, store

To load store data I use:

```
this.getTestStore().load({
    params: {
        item_id: record.get('id')
    }
});
```

How to obtain last load params (`{ item_id: record.get('id') }`) from this store in the future?

Comment: Why don't you just save a reference to it yourself?

Comment: Too much references for myself )

Comment: `this.lastId = record.get('id');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your store:

store.lastOptions.params

Comment: No I didn't ). Found this in parent `AbstractStore` class